# passing belongs_to relationship back to model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a user model that has an association with a school (user contains a foreign key called school_id). When a user registers (or create), the user has the option to specify a school that they attend. The problem I'm currently having is that I'm unsure how to set the school_id once the user passes the school name. I'm currently getting the error, "undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass" for:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId

  belongs_to :school

  #... other code

  before_validation :find_school_id

  def find_school_id
    self.school_id = School.find_by(name: self.school).id
  end
end
```

**View**

```
<div>
  <%= f.label :school %>
  <%= f.autocomplete_field :school, autocomplete_school_name_suggestions_path %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

Model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId

  belongs_to :school

  #... other code

  before_validation :find_school_id

  def school_name=(value)
    self.school = School.find_by(name: value)
  end

  def school_name
    school && school.name
  end
end
```

View:

```
<div>
  <%= f.label :school_name %>
  <%= f.autocomplete_field :school_name, autocomplete_school_name_suggestions_path %>
</div>
```

Comment: Couldn't your additions be done by just adding an attr_accessor school_name?

Comment: @thestig - It can't. attr_accessor creates both setter and getter method based on instance variable, we want them to be based on the associated object.

Comment: okay, well the reason why I asked that is because I wasn't able to get it working with the code you provided. By add attr_accessor I was able to get it to work. I'll look into this

Comment: What error did you get? Using attr_accessor won't raise anything but it also won't store the association in a database

Comment: There should be find_by instead of find in the setter. Also the getter may raise if no school is yet associated. Answer updated.